# How do you configure Javalin to render Pebble pages/templates?

Tags: java, html, javalin, pebble

I tried Search the documentation but I still don't understand. Here's my code to start up the app.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
          Javalin app = Javalin.create(
                config -> {
                    config.addStaticFiles("src/main/resources/public", Location.EXTERNAL);
                }
             );
          app.start(9090);
          app.get("/", ctx -> {
              ctx.redirect("login.html");
          });

    }
```

on localhost:9090/login.html, The Login Page Displays The brackets.

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %} Login {% endblock %} {% block content %}
{{success}}

Login In

Username  
password  

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Search this page https://javalin.io/documentation#faq for pebble

Comment: JavalinPebble.configure(PebbleEngine.builder().build())

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

In your Javalin route you are perforing a redirect:

```
ctx.redirect("login.html");
```

Instead of redirecting to a template, you should redirect to a path - and then handle the rendering of the template in that path.

Also, to avoid needing to explicitly configure a Pebble rendering engine (in other words, to use Pebble as the default renderer) you can change your pebble template file suffixes from `.html` to `.peb`.

(If you use `.html` then Javalin will expect you to be using Thymeleaf, not Pebble.)

---

**The Template Files**

Both of the Pebble template files need to be placed in the standard `resources` folder under `src`, with a suitable file extension. As per the [documentation](https://javalin.io/documentation):

> Javalin looks for templates/markdown files in src/resources, and uses the correct rendering engine based on the extension of your template.

**Do not place your templates in the `public` static files directory! These template files are not meant to be directly accessible to end users.**

Both of the Pebble templates are renamed to:

- `base.peb`
- `login.peb`

Note the file suffix.

In `login.peb` I also changed the `extends` directive to refer to the renamed base template:

```
{% extends "base.peb" %}
```

---

**The Javalin Routes**

To handle the redirect you can use the following routes:

```java
app.get("/", ctx -> {
    ctx.redirect("/login");
});
        
app.get("/login", ctx -> {
    ctx.render("login.peb");
});
```

The `/` route redirects to the `/login` route. That second route handles rendering of the `login.peb` template.

This is why you were seeing a raw template in the browser: The redirect was returning the unrendered template file, instead of returning a route.

Also, by using this approach, the URL displayed in the address bar will be correct: `http://localhost:9090/login`

---

**Update**

I forgot to mention a separate point: I recommend you do *not* use this:

```
config.addStaticFiles("src/main/resources/public", Location.EXTERNAL);
```

That location is not external to the application and anyway you should not force the deployed application to rely on a `src` directory. The more typical approach is this:

```
config.addStaticFiles("/public", Location.CLASSPATH);
```

(Or, use a truly external path, completely outside of your application's location.)